# Building Clinic management system in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm welling to develop a simple CMS application with Java EE. It contains these modules:

1. add/search patients
2. patients time booking
3. doctor's area (diagnosis , prescription ..etc)
4. admin area (adding/modifying system users .. etc)

But I'm confused about what framework to use : JSF, Grails id Struts.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend You Grails Framework. All activities you have written can be implemented really fast. If u have not a big knowledge about Grails I recommend you this book: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started

It's for older version of Grails, but a lot of things didn't change so you would be able to start your project fast. Grails has also very good documeentation, most answers I was looking for I found there.

For users managments I will recommend you Spring Security Core plugin which allows you to implement such features as role managment for example.

Don't be afraid about Groovy language, it's very similar to pure Java. A lot of programmers would exactly say: it IS Java.

Good luck with your project! :)

Comment: If u know Java, you don't need to learn additionally Groovy, it's very similar to Java and all features you need to Grails are well showed in Grails documentation. I've not been reading anything about Groovy and I'm finishing my thirth project in Grails. If you really need to learn Groovy for some reason (for example you don't know Java :)), look for some tutorials in Google, it will be enough.